# Unable to load a resource in flutter

Tags: file, flutter, dart

I'm trying to read a file in a flutter app.

The file exists in:

```
/assets/timezone/data/2019b.tzf
```

My pubspec contains:

```
- assets/timezone/data/2019b.tzf
```

My dart code calls:

```
rootBundle.load('packages/timezone/data/2019b.tzf');
```

Flutter returns the following:

```
Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (Unable to load asset: assets/timezone/data/2019b.tzf)
```

Unit Test

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  group("Test Load", () {
    test("load", () async {
      try {
        ByteData byteData =
            await rootBundle.load('assets/timezone/data/2019b.tzf');

          print("loaded successfully size: ${byteData.buffer.lengthInBytes}");
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
      print("done");
    });
  });
}*
```

pubspec.yaml

```
name: regions
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
assets:
    - assets/timezone/data/2019b.tzf
```

Directory tree:

```
├── assets
│   └── timezone
│       └── data
│           ├── 2019b.tzf
├── lib
├── pubspec.yaml
├── test
│   └── region_test.dart
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `rootBundle.load('assets/timezone/data/2019b.tzf')` only in your app.

In tests you can do this:

```
final bytes = File('assets/timezone/data/2019b.tzf').readAsBytesSync();
final byteData = ByteData.view(bytes.buffer);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the pubspec.yaml, Replace '**2019b.tzf**' with latest database version (it's currently '**2020d.tzf**').
**also you can use 'latest.tzf'**

```
flutter:
  ..
  ..
  assets:
    ..
    ..
    - assets/timezone/data/latest.tzf
```